# Multiple objects from parsed json in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

The model I am using:

```
 class ExerciseSession{
      final String Id;
      final String cw_id;
      final String client_id;
      final String date;
      final int challenge_rating;
      final String apiCode;
      final String userId;
    
      ExerciseSession({this.Id, this.cw_id, this.client_id, this.date,
        this.challenge_rating, this.apiCode, this.userId});
    
      factory ExerciseSession.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json){
        return ExerciseSession(
            Id: json['session_id'],
            cw_id: json['cw_id'],
            client_id: json['client_id'],
            date: json['session_date'],
            challenge_rating: json['challenge_rating'],
        );
      }
    
      Map<String, String> toBodyMap()=>{
      "cwId" : this.cw_id,
      "clientid" : this.client_id,
      "sessionDate" : this.date,
      "challengeRating" : this.challenge_rating.toString(),
        "apiCode" : this.apiCode,
        "userId" : this.userId,
      };
    }
    
    class ExerciseList {
      final List<ExerciseSession> sessions;
    
      ExerciseList({this.sessions});
    
      factory ExerciseList.fromJSON(List<dynamic> json){
    
        List<ExerciseSession> sessions = new List<ExerciseSession>();
        sessions = json.map((i)=>ExerciseSession.fromJSON(i)).toList();
    
        return new ExerciseList(
            sessions: sessions
        );
      }
    }
```

The code I am using to get the json from server:

```
Future<ExerciseList> getExercises(String userId, String clientId,
      {DateTime singleDate, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate}) async {
    print("Future Get Exercises");
    String _userId = userId;
    String _clientId = clientId;

    ExerciseList sessions;

    if(singleDate != null){
      String _onDate = singleDate.toIso8601String();
    print("Single Date Set");
    http.post(phpUrl, body: {'userId':_userId, 'clientid':_clientId, 'onDate':_onDate, 'apiCode':apc.getExercisesFromOneDate_AC}).then((response){
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        sessions = ExerciseList.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to Get Assessments");
      }
    });
  } else if(fromDate != null && toDate != null){
      String _fromDate = fromDate.toIso8601String();
      String _toDate = toDate.toIso8601String();
    print("From to Date Set");
    http.post(phpUrl, body: {'userId':_userId, 'clientid':_clientId, 'fromDate':_fromDate, 'toDate':_toDate, 'apiCode':apc.getExercisesDateRange_AC}).then((response){
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        sessions = ExerciseList.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to Get Assessments");
      }
    });
  } else if(fromDate != null){
      String _fromDate = fromDate.toIso8601String();
    print("From Date Set");
    http.post(phpUrl, body: {'userId':_userId, 'clientid':_clientId, 'fromDate':_fromDate, 'apiCode':apc.getExercisesFromDate_AC}).then((response){
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        sessions = ExerciseList.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to Get Assessments");
      }
    });
  } else {
    print("No Dates Set");
    http.post(phpUrl, body: {'userId':_userId, 'clientid':_clientId, 'apiCode':apc.getExercises_AC}).then((response){
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        sessions = ExerciseList.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to Get Assessments");
      }
    });
  }

    return sessions;
  }
```

my Test response code:

```
void _getAllExercises() async{
    print("[$TAG : INFO] - Getting Exercises");
    ExerciseList getList = await exerRest.getExercises("1", "2");
    ExerciseSession session = getList.sessions[0];
    print("[TAG : INFO] - Exercise Session Test All challenge rating ${session.challenge_rating}");
  }
```

and the console output:

```
I/flutter ( 8157): [DEBUG SCREEN : INFO] - Getting Exercises
I/flutter ( 8157): Future Get Exercises
I/flutter ( 8157): No Dates Set
I/flutter ( 8157): Response status: 200
I/flutter ( 8157): Response body: [{"session_id":"10","cw_id":"1","client_id":"2","session_date":"2018-08-23","challenge_rating":"0"},{"session_id":"15","cw_id":"1","client_id":"2","session_date":"2018-08-23","challenge_rating":"1"},{"session_id":"17","cw_id":"1","client_id":"2","session_date":"2018-08-23","challenge_rating":"2"}]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong it looks to me like that should all work, but clearly I am missing something,

I suspect its a mix up between my model .fromJson and the json itself.

Comment: You posted a lot of code and logs, but didn't describe what the actual problem is. What is not working???

Comment: the problem is that print("[TAG : INFO] - Exercise Session Test All challenge rating ${session.challenge_rating}"); doesn't seem to be print out anything at all.

Comment: Did you try debugging with breakpoints to see whats happening step by step? Are you using Android Studio or VS Code?

Comment: Try to debug it with print(json) inside the fromJSON. Or on a specific index

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems that you're trying to parse the data that has already been decoded and parsed on `sessions = ExerciseList.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));`. If you're just trying to return `List<ExerciseSession>`, you can consider using List.add()

```dart
List<ExerciseSession> sessions;

...

sessions.add(ExerciseSession.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)));
```

I find it odd that from your report, `print()` doesn't push through. You can try adding breakpoints to check if the List/Object gets the expected value by using `List.length` before trying to print.